# Installed PU/CU on all farm servers but SharePoint thinks it's missing from one of application Server

Tags: sharepoint-server, configuration-wizard

Recently I find one issue in my Central Admin, i.e "Product / patch installation or server upgrade required on one of our Application Server. Even I did run the PowerShell cmdlet Get-SPProduct -local and refreshed configuration wizard  as per [Blog](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/588364fc-6989-46b1-99b4-35c539ed1b61/installed-march-pucu-on-all-farm-servers-but-sharepoint-thinks-its-missing-from-wfes?forum=sharepointadmin&prof=required) but, Issue still existed and configuration wizard getting errors. Please advise me.

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Srinu Dasari.

Comment: Have you ran the wizard on the servers that are 'missing' the patches? If yes - did you try with the get-spproduct -local and than rerun the wizard? I've had this happen quite a lot (2013). However, I've had occasions too were after upgrading a server, there were additional patches that needed to be applied.

Comment: Yes @Christoffer I did. But, configuration wizard ends up with an error message that states , patches are missing.

Comment: The patches that are missing: google the KB number and download and apply those patches to the servers where they are missing. I had this happends once before.

Comment: But, Here is the problem, when I try to install KB, getting error that was saying already installed.

Comment: Have you tried to reboot the server(s)? Either that or run the wizard using the psconfig/sharepoint cmd shell.

Comment: PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures

Comment: I used following command:PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install
But no luck...

Comment: Superweird. Have you restarted the application server?

Comment: Yes, rebooted. I did everything, except uninstall patches, which is causing problem. But removing  update is not recommended.

Comment: I've never uninstalled any patches so I cant comment on that. However as you have tried rebooting, using get-spproduct, installing the patches separately, running the psconfig using powershell instead of the wizard in the UI. One last thing you can try is to run the CMD as admin using this: psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd -installcheck -noinstallcheck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of struggling, I found that Installer folder under C:\Windows directory is missing. So, here How I closed issue:

1. Create an empty folder under C:\Windows directory.
2. Copy files from C:\Windows\Installer folder from another working server to present server.
3. Restore-InstallerFiles.ps1 powershell downloaded by from [Here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Restore-the-Missing-d11de3a1.)
4. Run Restore-InstallerFiles.ps1 to installe missed installer files.
5. Run Get-SPProduct -Local from SharePoint PowerShell.

Now Missing/Required error disappeared and able to run Configuration Wizard without any issues.

Thanks For Everyone

Answer (score 0):

This error usually pops up when you have not installed the patches in the right way.

Although it doesn't matter but I have always followed the practice of installing the patch on the Application server first(where CA is hosted) and then installing it in the remaining WFE servers and so on.

The best way to solve this issue would be to uninstall the installed patches and install the update again starting with the Application server.

Let me know if you are able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply, @yash.kamdar, unistall patches on which server?

Comment: I guess you already posted an answer that worked for you. Nice work !!!

Answer (score 0):

Just run in SharePoint V Management Shell this command after your sure all updates are installed on servers farm:

```
PSCONFIG.EXE -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd installcheck -noinstallcheck
```